# The specified deps.json does not exist

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

This problem occurs on the latest update of VS 2019 along with ASP.NET Core 2.2 and Entity Framework when you try to `update-database` or `add-migration`. It appears only on my HP Omen laptop while it works on my Lenovo.

`The specified deps.json [...] does not exist`. It is trying to find x.deps.json in project's directory while it is found at: `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2`.

I tried the following solutions and they didn't work out:

- Deleting `Platform: MCD` in Environment Variables - it simply didn't exist on my laptop;
- `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2` -> `bin\MCD\Debug\netcoreapp2.2`;
- Clearing NuGet's cache;
- I doubt having anything wrong in appsettings.json since it worked fine on my other laptop;
- Default project is selected in Package Manager Console;
- `dotnet ef database update -v`. Note that This **worked** but in VS it still doesn't.

I also restarted my machine after trying those solutions.

My .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Binance.Net" Version="4.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.AspNetCore" Version="1.7.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.Core" Version="1.7.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.SqlServer" Version="1.7.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NSwag.AspNetCore" Version="13.0.6" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

My Environment Variables:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> ls env:

Name                           Value
----                           -----
ALLUSERSPROFILE                C:\ProgramData
APPDATA                        C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming
ChocolateyInstall              C:\ProgramData\chocolatey
ChocolateyLastPathUpdate       Fri Feb  1 21:10:26 2019
CommonProgramFiles             C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)        C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432             C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME                   DESKTOP-VB77N85
ComSpec                        C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
DriverData                     C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
DXSDK_DIR                      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\
HOMEDRIVE                      C:
HOMEPATH                       \Users\Admin
LOCALAPPDATA                   C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER                    \\DESKTOP-VB77N85
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS           12
OneDrive                       C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive
OS                             Windows_NT
Path                           C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Boxstarter;C:\Program Files (x86)\Com...
PATHEXT                        .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.CPL
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE         AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER           Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL                6
PROCESSOR_REVISION             9e0a
ProgramData                    C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles                   C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)              C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432                   C:\Program Files
PSModulePath                   C:\Users\Admin\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\ProgramData\Boxstarter;C:\Progr...
PUBLIC                         C:\Users\Public
QtMsBuild                      C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\QtMsBuild
SystemDrive                    C:
SystemRoot                     C:\WINDOWS
TEMP                           C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP                            C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp
USERDOMAIN                     DESKTOP-VB77N85
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE      DESKTOP-VB77N85
USERNAME                       Admin
USERPROFILE                    C:\Users\Admin
VS100COMNTOOLS                 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\
windir                         C:\WINDOWS
```

I tried everything I found on github/stackoverflow/Google search. I don't know what's wrong. Since the dotnet command worked, I think that it might be from Environment Variables.

Any ideas? I can use the dotnet command as a solution but it's better to fix it through VS.

Comment: One maybe stupid question but didn't you run `git clean -xdf` and the run `dotnet restore` on the whole solution? Also, is this package included somewhere as a peer dependency? Otherwise I'd try installing it. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools/

Comment: I just ran it and same stuff. That package should be included in ASP.NET Core 2.2. I don't think it's the package causing it because it works fine on my other laptop and the project is literally copy/pasted with the only difference that it is recompiled. Somehow Visual Studio doesn't recognize `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2` directory. It thinks that the output files are found in project's folder.

Comment: No, it doesn't necessarily have to be included. I'd install it manually and try again. I think that's actual cause.

Comment: Just installed it. Same story.